# Detecting color in PostScript files

Tags: postscript

I have a need to determine if a postscript file was sent to the printer in color or black and white. While there are many solutions out there, they mostly seem to requires rendering the document and then checking each page individually using ghostscript, which can be a bit slow for larger documents. I was wondering if the following grep would give me the same info or if there are other types of colors missing?

`grep 'setrgbcolor\|setcymkcolor\|colorimage' foo.prn`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are a very long way short of the full range of colour spaces available in PostScript. You don't have `setcolorspace` and setcolorspace takes a complex array of arguments which can include /DeviceGray (so not colour).

You also aren't accounting for CIEBasedA nor the fact that C=M=Y=0, K is grayscale even though it is expressed in CMYK space, and of course R=G=B is s shade of gray expressed in RGB space. Similarly /Separataion /Black will draw in a shade of gray.

In addition, PostScript is a programming language; its very common to include a prolog which defines operations in a way convenient to the author of the PostScript-generating application. The prolog can include functions which are not used in this particular program. So something like:

```
/rg /setrgbcolor load def
```

would trigger your grep, even if the PostScript program didn't then use `rg`.

Then there are images. `colorimage` is not the only way to draw an image in PostScript, the `image` operator takes a dictionary operand, and that can include a colour space. As above, its possible to have a gray image expressed in a different colour space (inefficient, possibly, but legal).

You can write a PostScript program which 'hooks' the definition of the colour operators and have that code interrogate the parameters to decide if the specification is a gray space or not, images are much harder to deal with since, if you want reliability, you need to look at the image sample data to see whether its actually just a gray image.

Its possible to write a Ghostscript device which could do the job, because it will receive all the operations. It still won't be entirely fast as it has to interpret the entire file in order to detect every operation. Even then such a tool could be defeated in particular applications. For example the code could interrogate the underlying device and take a different code path if the device colour space was Gray, RGB or CMYK. But that's highly unlikely to happen in any real world PostScript program.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed explanation!

Comment: As a follow up, I'm trying to determine what CMYK values would be considered black & white/grayscale and which would be considered color (use case is print billing). Would you happen to have any resources where I could read up about this stiff?

Comment: Well, personally I'd consider anything where C=M=Y=0 and K != 0 to be grayscale. Normally PostScript users try to avoid 'rich black' produced by combining equal values of C, M & Y, because it usually produces a brown colour instead when using real inks and media. So any CMYK colour specification where any of the first 3 channels is non-zero would be colour.

Comment: "So any CMYK colour specification where any of the first 3 channels is non-zero would be colour."

Even if C=M=Y=0 and K != 0?

Comment: The first three channels in your comment are all zero, that was rather the point I was making. If C=M=Y=0 then whatever K is, its a shade of gray, and therefore **not** colour. The first sentence in my comment even specifically states C=M=Y=0 and K!=0 is grayscale.

Comment: Im sorry, I messed up my question! I'm asking for clarification when C=M=Y>0 and K != 0 - would that visibly color or just b/w?

Comment: I did cover that too, by implication. That's a 'rich black' and generally smart users avoid it, because what it produces is often a shade of mud. Its up to you whether to regard that as 'black' or 'colour'. Its usually caused by naive colour conversions from other colour spaces and should probably be considered black IMO. But visually it may be a dark brown or purplish colour.